# Change file name with excel table

Tags: powershell

I have a Excel file with the current filename and new filename, both are the whole path to the files. I would like to write a PowerShell script to change the filename.

I have created a csv file but I don't know how to create this within the `for each` iteration.

Comment: Please provide what you've tried so far. Check out the [Asking help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), and the page on [What types of questions should I avoid asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

With a CSV file with the data like this:

```
OldName,NewName
C:\folder\file.txt,new_file.txt
C:\folder\song.mp3,different_song.mp3
```

This code will rename each file:

```
$files = Import-Csv "C:\folder\rename_files.csv"

foreach ($file in $files){
  Rename-Item -Path $file.OldName -NewName $file.NewName -Verbose
}
```